# Calculating the number of cycles under linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, assembly

I have an assembly code which is 100 times these two instructions :

```
    movl    %eax, -16(%rbp)
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
```

that's corresponding to this c code loop:

```
 int i;
    int a=5, b;
    for (i=0 ; i < sptr->numberOfIterations ; i += 100){
        b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
        b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
        b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
        b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
        b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
        b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
        b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
        b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
        b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
        b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a; // 100 assignments 
    }
```

why does the operation of b=a; go to two instructions ? and how comes that I calculate the number of cycles it takes (each `b=a;`) is one cycle?

I compiled it with `g++`

Comment: if it was compiled with `g++`, what's up with the C tag?

Comment: How are you calculating the number of cycles? What target CPU is this? Are you aware of out-of-order and superscalar execution? Pipelining? What are you ultimately trying to find out?

Comment: The compiler realizes all the previous assignments have no effect on the final outcome of the program (logically), so I only generates assembly for the last `b=a`.

Comment: What is the point of this anyway?

Comment: @Chris you are wrong there are 200 time the b=a assignment, as noted in the question.

Comment: @pmjordan how do you do if the two operations are superscalar?

Comment: Are you counting the total cycles, then dividing by 100? With the techniques that pmjordan mentioned, it is possible (and likely with your code) that your cycles per instruction (CPI) is less than 1 (superscalar capabilities are the only thing that can cause this). That is, if you have N functional units, you can theoretically compute N instructions per cycle for a CPI of 1/N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give the compiler the chance to optimize the code. With the proper optimization flags `-O3 -march=native` my compiler (gcc) is able to reduce all of that to the following line:

```
movl    $5, %eax
```

no loop, repetition of the code, nothing.

So your compiler may or may not do optimizations and a lot of stuff that you don't see. And processors are different. Mine here is able to put the constant 5 into an immediate and doesn't create the variable `a` at all.

Answer (score 3):

b=`a` *does take* two instructions: first move `a`'s value into a register, then move that register's value into `b`'s memory address:

```
movl    %eax, -16(%rbp) // move a's value to eax
movl    -12(%rbp), %eax // move eax's value into b's address.
```

Since you are repeating this instruction over and over again, the compiler realizes that one `b=a` will be the same as 100. Therefore, it just reduces that for loop into a single `b=a` instruction.

**EDIT**: since you say these lines appear 100 times, then the compiler is performing **no optmimizations** on your code. The ASM result of your code is exactly what you wrote, 100 times `b=a`.

Comment: it is not true ! read the question, I remarked it again. these 2 lines appear 100 times!

Comment: There, editted. You should try to express yourself better. Nobody understood what you ment.

Comment: No, nothing happens in parallel unless you do it parallel yourself. These instructions are executed sequentially.

Comment: But a modern processor is pipelined and superscalar. So, in reality a instruction needs about 20 cycles from instruction fetch to store retirement, but as 20 of them are executed in a pipline, each in different stages of completion, they appear to need one cycle each. Additionally several independent instruction may be executed in parallel (for intance up to four on a core 2), if they don't use the same execution units and several other conditions are met.

Comment: Okay okay, i knew somebody was going to say this. Nowadays there is an implicit paralellism on instructions. I don't think OP was looking for pipelined and superscalar instruction execution. BTW, a write and read instructions that access EAX one after the other won't be paralellized that much, they're completely dependant on each other. What do you mean by "several independent instructions...". Your code won't be executed on multiple cores unless you explicitly create a thread/process and divide the workload into those 2 processing units...

Comment: Even with the %eax dependency, the processor can realize that there is not a true data dependency on %eax. Modern processors map logical registers to internal registers. The cpu can instead issue the first two instructions using some internal register for %eax, but then simultaneously issue the next two instructions and use a different internal register for %eax.

Answer (score 1):

Under any reasonable compiler with any reasonable optimization settings, this code:

```
int i;
int a=5, b;
for (i=0 ; i < sptr->numberOfIterations ; i += 100){
    b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
    b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
    b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
    b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
    b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
    b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
    b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
    b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
    b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;
    b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a;b=a; // 100 assignments 
}
```

Will be optimized into:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i < sptr->numberOfIterations; i += 100); // Possibly further reduced from O(n) into O(1).
int a = 5;
int b = 5;
```

Or, if `i`, `a` and `b` are never used, then the compiler could optimize it into this:

```
;
```

Comment: Or at least, it would be optimized to something with a single `b=a;` assignment inside the loop. I'm not particularly sure your "optimization" is correct (what should happen when `sptr->numberOfIterations` is not a multiple of 100)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yeah. I noticed that as well. I've since updated the answer with a more accurate answer. However, if none of these values are ever used, then the compiler could just remove the whole thing.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: There's also interesting things that can happen if `numberOfIterations` is negative. But since `b` is undefined at start, it should be allowed to magically start as `5`.